# Giving error while saving the text with tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I am developing MVC application using EF 4.0.

I am trying to put value , `<test>` to the address field but while saving its gives an below error , how to solve it ?

A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (Address="`<test>`").

**Edit**

Please check below code

```
namespace CEntities
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(EmployeeMetaData))]
    public partial class Employee
    {
    }

     /// <summary>
     /// Holds the validations for Employee class
     /// </summary>
     public class EmployeeMetaData
     {
         [Key]
         public int Id { get; set; }
         [Required]
         [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "First name can accept maximum 50 characters.")]
         public string FirstName { get; set; }

         [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Last name can accept maximum 50 characters.")]
         public string LastName { get; set; }

         [StringLength(1000, ErrorMessage = "Address can accept maximum 1000 characters.")]
         public string Address { get; set; }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ValidateInput(false)` to turn off `Request Validation` or you can add `[AllowHtml]` Attribute to your model property

**Edited** :

add `[AllowHtml]` attribute on Address model property.

```
[StringLength(1000, ErrorMessage = "Address can accept maximum 1000 characters.")]
[AllowHtml]
public string Address { get; set; }
```

and add `using System.Web.Mvc;`  directive on top.

Are you using Assembly System.Web.Mvc.dll, version 4 or version 2.

`[AllowHtml]` attribute is in `Assembly System.Web.Mvc.dll, version 4`. check your assembly version to apply this.

Comment: Thanks...But I am unable to add [AllowHtml]. its giving the error.The type or namespace name 'AllowHtml' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: .The type or namespace name 'AllowHtml' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: did you added the `using System.Web.Mvc;` directive in the model class?

Comment: yes still not working, all other DataAnnotations works but not this one.

Comment: did you make changes as I posted in updated answer. if yes, than is some compilation error coming or not?

Comment: same error, [AllowHtml] attribute is not  available. I have added System.Web.Mvc directive but still its not working. Is this issue related DataAnnotations ?

Comment: Are you using Assembly System.Web.Mvc.dll, version 4 or  version 2. [AllowHtml] attribute is in v4. check your version.

Comment: Version 2.0 , is that issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code

> namespace CEntities

{

```
[MetadataType(typeof(EmployeeMetaData))]
```

public partial class Employee

```
{



}
```

> ```
>  /// <summary>
>  /// Holds the validations for Employee class
>  /// </summary>
>  public class EmployeeMetaData
>  {
>      [Key]
>      public int Id { get; set; }
>      [Required]
>      [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "First name can accept maximum 50 characters.")]
>      public string FirstName { get; set; }
> ```

```
     [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Last name can accept maximum 50 characters.")]
     public string LastName { get; set; }

     [StringLength(1000, ErrorMessage = "Address can accept maximum 1000 characters.")]
     public string Address { get; set; }

  }
```

}

Comment: Delete this (click the delete link under the answer,) since this is an update to your question not an answer. It has already been added to your question. Normally you just click `edit` under your question to add to it.

Answer (score 0):

@YograjGupta gave you a good answer, I'm not sure why `[AllowHtml]` is not working. Another option is in the controller, were you save the `EmployeeMetaData` to the database, you can add  `db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;`, before you save changes. You will also have to remove the `if(ModelState.IsValid)` part.

Another option would be to replace the `<` and `>` with `employeeMetaData.Address.Replace("<", "&lt;").Replace(">", "&gt;")`

Keep in mind that if you use the `[AllowHtml]` attribute, it makes you more vulnerable to hacking, so you may want to remove it before your final release. Or you can add `Microsoft.Security.Application` and do something like `Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(address)` to remove unsafe html.

**Edit**

Your controller should look something like this:

```
public ActionResult Create(Employee employee)
{
    employee.Address = employee.Address.Replace("<", "&lt;").Replace(">", "&gt;");
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Employees.Add(employee);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Or you could try this:

```
public ActionResult Create(Employee employee)
{
    db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
    db.Employees.Add(employee);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

`db` is your database and `Employee` is the Employee table in your database.

Comment: Thanks Garrett and Yograj. I think, Garrett is right. Actually I am testing my application and I have come across situation where user can put text in angular brackets, its not abt each time there will be some html tag , but anything which in angular bracket should be acceptable, so I am trying insert it.

Comment: @ Yograj and @ Garrett, How can I use below code ? employeeMetaData.Address.Replace("<", "&lt;").Replace(">", "&gt;") ?

Comment: @nilesh1foru the string that contains the `>` and `<` symbols, lets call it `addressString`, you would do something like `addressString = addressString.Address.Replace("<", "&lt;").Replace(">", "&gt;")`. However I still recoment using @Yograj's answer, trying to get `[AllowHtml]` to work. Also to display a string with html in a razor view, use `@Html.Raw(stringName)`.

Comment: @ Garrett, Where to put this code in Class/controller or in view ?

Comment: I have added below code in Employee controller, but befor cusrsor comes there error comes.   

`employee.Address.Replace("<", "&lt;").Replace(">", "&gt;");
db.Employees.Add(employee);
db.SaveChanges(); `

Comment: @nilesh1foru see my edit. I still recommend getting the `[AllowHtml]` attribute to work instead or also.